# How to change the webview background color in phonegap 2.7

Tags: cordova, android-webview

I am developing a App in Phonegap. And i have enable `<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />` in my `config.xml`.

And i am using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"` in Manifest.xml.

The Problem is. my index.html file is red background. so when i scroll up in the app its getting bounce in bottom and i am seeing white background :(. Its really annoying and spoil the whole app appearance.

So Now i want to change the white background into other color. or i want to use some image as background of the webview.

I am using `phonegap.2.7.0` Please help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: Try this one - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18096757/2266525

Answer (score -1):

Add following code in css file and import that css file

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page {

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f3ff, rgba(93, 177, 223, 0.75));

 }
```

you can use image as background or else use color